# ROS.org - how to switch to English

Tags: ros

[image: Rosanswers logo]

[image: image description]

This is how ros.org looks for computer in Japan. Unfortunately not everyone in Japan prefers Japanese language and wants to switch to English ros.org. I do not see such option there anywhere, so I ask here: How to switch into English?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/45780/ros.org---how-to-switch-to-english/) by [Tõnu Samuel](https://answers.ros.org/users/394/t%C3%B5nu-samuel/) on ROS Answers with karma: 161 on 2012-10-13

Post score: 4

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Tõnu Samuel](https://answers.ros.org/users/394/t%C3%B5nu-samuel/) on 2012-10-17**:
Today http://www.ros.org/wiki/turtlesim/Tutorials gives me English from Japan. Something changed? Was bug and now fixed?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

There is something wrong with the wiki search that creates that page. Must be corrected by the site administrator.

As quick workaround just delete the *ja* phrase from the url of requested page like this:

```
http://ros.org/wiki/ja/ROS/Tutorials/UnderstandingServicesParams
```

change to:

```
http://ros.org/wiki/ROS/Tutorials/UnderstandingServicesParams
```

and you will see the English version.

---

Originally posted by [Jakub](https://answers.ros.org/users/2948/jakub/) with karma: 1821 on 2012-10-13

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Tõnu Samuel](https://answers.ros.org/users/394/t%C3%B5nu-samuel/) on 2012-10-13**:
Next links countain "ja" but this page does not. I want to read this page :)

**Comment by [tfoote](https://answers.ros.org/users/3/tfoote/) on 2012-10-14**:
The search was finding both the Japanese and English versions.  I've suppressed the Japanese versions in the search.